# what should I do for connecting oppo A5 to Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I am trying to connect my Oppo A5 Android phone to Android studio but I am facing this issue

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

kindly guide me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following things to successfully connect your device with your laptop

1. Enable Developer option by tapping multiple times on build-number in your phone settings
2. Enable USB Debugging option in developer options
3. Connect your phone with original data cable and choose file sharing option from available connection method.

You can also connect your device with your android studio for app testing through wifi, for that you must have android version 11+ and your laptop and phone must be connected with the same Wifi. This is one of the convenient options to connect your device with android studio. Let me know if still your issue persists

Comment: I have Android 8 can I run on that?

Answer (score 0):

Wireless Debugging supports only from Android version 11. First check your android version is not below v11. Oppo A5s is coming with Android Oreo(8.0) from the box.